# How to get Workspace object in new TeamFoundation 2013 Templates

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

In new version of TeamFoundation 2013 default build templates, the `Workspace` variable is missing. It is needed as intput parameter for few key activities like `ConvertWorkspaceItem`. How do I get current workspace for TfvcTemplate.12.xaml templates? I've tried to use [this msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8ab3bf2-a6ce-4823-85e7-062ad5ca34df/tfs-2013-workspace?forum=tfsprocess) but it's not working for me (returns null workspace name). Any suggestions?

Comment: Be mindful that TFS 2013 has added a ResetEnvironemnt task in the finally portion of Try Compile,Test and Publish sequence. Any variable initialized prior to this reset task is cleared after compilation. This cost me three days of work trying to figure out why I was getting nullreference exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with a hack using internal classes from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.dll` (used by microsoft to create workspace name). You need to create custom activity with following code:

```
public sealed class GetDefaultWorkspace : BaseActivity<Workspace>
{     
    public override Activity CreateBody()
    {
        var type = typeof(TfGetSources).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.TeamFoundation.TfGetSources+GetDefaultWorkspaceName");

        var activity = (CodeActivity<string>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var sequence = new Sequence();
        var workspaceName = new Variable<string>();

        sequence.Variables.Add(workspaceName);
        sequence.Activities.Add(activity);
        activity.Result = (OutArgument<string>) workspaceName;

        sequence.Activities.Add(new GetWorkspace
            {
                Name = workspaceName,
                Result = new LambdaReference<Workspace>(ctx => Result.Get(ctx))
            });

        return sequence;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a new activity in 2013 called `GetLocalPath` that replaces ConvertWorkspaceItem.
The activity is under the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core` namespace in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities` assembly.

It uses the LocalPathProvider class that aggregates all workspaces used in the build and exposes path translation for all of them in one place. This basically removes the dependency of knowing the workspace in order to translate server paths to local paths and allows you to use as many workspaces as you want without worrying about breaking something down the line.

When MS takes something away,  it's usually for a good reason. "hacking" is really not necessary.

Comment: Right for getting the local path. What if I want to check out some files during the build?

Comment: If I remember correctly (A while since I poked around that IL) as long as you use the activities for doing a 'manual' get also add their mapping for GetLocalPath.

Comment: Make sure you realize this is a new activity in the TOOLBOX - you can't just call the method directly

Answer (score 2):

This answer might work better for some people.  ghord's answer works well, and passes the Workspace back where it can be used in the XAML.  However, for my purposes I only want the workspace in my custom TFS activities, so I ended up with this alternative...

```
public sealed class CustomActivity : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // get workspace
        var buildDetail = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
        var buildAgent = context.GetExtension<IBuildAgent>();
        var buildDirectory = buildAgent.GetExpandedBuildDirectory(buildDetail.BuildDefinition);
        var workspacePath = Path.Combine(buildDirectory, "src");
        var wsInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(workspacePath);
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wsInfo.ServerUri);
        tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);
        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        // finally can get to the workspace here
        var workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(workspacePath);
    }
}
```

Using this method, I don't have to have an activity that just returns the workspace, and then have to pass the workspace into other TFS activities.  I just get the workspace from within my own activity while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method employed here will use the already downloaded workspace. Keep in mind, that this approach will only work within the scope of "Run on agent" sequence after "Initialize Environment" and before ResetEnvironment within the finally statement of Try Compile, Test, Publish. Else, the workflow will have no knowledge of a sources directory.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/420ba073-bdf5-4ab4-88da-c84561d1a1ba/creating-dynamic-working-folder-in-tfs2013-defaulttemplate?forum=tfsbuild