# TFS custom activity is reporting the TFS workspace is deleted

Tags: tfs

I have a custom TFS activity that returns the current workspace.  The code I am using was found in this post, and is reproduced here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045346/131270

```
public sealed class GetDefaultWorkspace : BaseActivity<Workspace>
{     
    public override Activity CreateBody()
    {
        var type = typeof(TfGetSources).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.TeamFoundation.TfGetSources+GetDefaultWorkspaceName");

        var activity = (CodeActivity<string>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var sequence = new Sequence();
        var workspaceName = new Variable<string>();

        sequence.Variables.Add(workspaceName);
        sequence.Activities.Add(activity);
        activity.Result = (OutArgument<string>) workspaceName;

        sequence.Activities.Add(new GetWorkspace
            {
                Name = workspaceName,
                Result = new LambdaReference<Workspace>(ctx => Result.Get(ctx))
            });

        return sequence;
    }
}
```

I return the value of this into a Workspace typed variable, and then pass that into another custom TFS activity that needs the workspace to check an item in.

I unwrap the workspace using...

```
    public InArgument<Workspace> Workspace { get; set; }

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute()
    {
        var workspace = _context.GetValue<Workspace>(Workspace);
```

The returned workspace exists, but it is reported as deleted...

```
Exception Message: The workspace 10_1_RQ-SRV-TFS-12r2;NETWORK SERVICE has been deleted. (type WorkspaceDeletedException) Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PendEdit(String path) at RQTfsActivities.RQSetVersion.Execute()
```

The log file shows the passed in workspace as...

```
Inputs 
    Workspace: 10_1_RQ-SRV-TFS-12r2;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the GetDefaultWorkspace activity was placed after the Initialize Environment activity but before the Get Sources activity, it showed deleted.  I moved GetDefaultWorkspace to after the Get Sources activity and it worked.